# AWS Glue Test Connection Logs

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I've set up an AWS Glue connection to an RDS database (in the same account and region). When doing the test connection I get the following error

```
rds-prod-snapshot test connection failed. For more information see the logs
```

Following the link to CloudWatch I get the error

```
There was an error getting log events.
The specified log stream does not exist.
```

The role has IAM permissions for CloudWatch logs

I followed the troubleshooting doc to get this far >  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-test-connection-failed/ (in fact I got most of these resolved when setting up the connection in the first place and resolved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out `AWSGlueServiceRole` policy was not attached to the role